# jquery plupload multipart_params

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using "plupload" plugin.

I have this input form :

```
<div id="flash_uploader" style="width: 610px; height: 330px;">You browser doesn't have Flash installed.</div><input type="text" name="categorie" id ="categorie" value="" /><input type="submit" value="send" />
```

I try to get the value of "categorie" with "multipart_params" but this doesn't work !

```
$("#flash_uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'flash',
    url : '../scripts/plupload/examples/upload.php',
    max_file_size : '700kb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    unique_names : false,
    multi_selection : true,
    multipart : true,
    multipart_params : {categorie : $('#categorie').val()},
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,png"}
    ],
    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    resize : {width : 550, height : 550, quality : 94},
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '../scripts/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf'
});
```

How can I **send the input "categorie" value** in the pluploadQueue to ../scripts/plupload/examples/upload.php ?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: So did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same one. Cheers.

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the parameter [this post](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=42) could help.

Comment: Use multipart_params!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535462/how-to-send-additional-data-using-plupload

Answer (score 8):

After block

```
$("#flash_uploader").pluploadQueue({...})
```

Bind **BeforeUpload** event

```
var uploader = $('#flash_uploader').pluploadQueue();
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up) {
  up.settings.multipart_params.tags = $('#categorie').val();
});
```

It works for me, hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: if we are not using multipart then

Comment: The usage  "up.settings.multipart_params.tags" is bit misleading (at least for me). It would be more clear as "up.settings.multipart_params.<key-name>"

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Plupload there are a few changes...

1. `BeforeUploadChunk` event (recommended in examples on Plupload website) no longer fires
2. `multipart_params` is now deprecated, replaced with `params`
3. You should use `setOptions` instead of setting the object properties directly

This is the snippet that worked for me...

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  //snip
  init: {
    UploadFile: function(up,file) {
      up.setOption("params",{file_id:file.id});
    }
  }
};
uploader.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the basic javascript upload (provided in the example) you can use this:
(assuming you have an input id="nuova_categoria" and/or input id="categoria_esistente")

```
init: {
    PostInit: function() {
        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

        document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
            uploader.settings.multipart_params.new_cat = $('#nuova_categoria').val();
            uploader.settings.multipart_params.existing_cat = $('#categoria_esistente').val();
            uploader.start();
            return false;
        };
    },
```

it triggers 'onclick' the value in those input fields.
Hope this will help.
Marco - www.infoarredo.it