# How to send additional data using PLupload?

Tags: php, jquery, upload, plupload

I'm using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com) to make an ajax file uploading.
Now the plupload.Uploader class has many options but none are additional data.

For Example :

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles',
    container : 'contact_container',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    url : 'upload.php',
    flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
    ],
    resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90}
});
```

What i'm trying to achive is i have a folder in my server where all the uploads 
are being saved.
I neeed inside the folder to create a sub-folder to each user that have uploaded files there.
How can i add data like id of the user to the instance of plupload.Uploader?
Or if i'll wrap a form inside the container div, will i be able to see it in the $_REQUEST?
Or is there some other way i can achive this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Have you tried using the setting for multipart_params? Add an additional option to your plupload.Uploader like so:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles',
    container : 'contact_container',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    url : 'upload.php',
    flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
    ],
    resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
    multipart_params : {
        "name1" : "value1",
        "name2" : "value2"
    }
});
```

You will then need to process the values in the file that handles the upload (upload.php by default). I think the values are captured by `$_POST` but you can use `$_REQUEST` just to be sure.

I've used jQuery to assign values on the fly, so instead of `"name1" : "value1"` you can use something like `"name1" : $("#name1").val(),` where #name1 might be an input elsewhere on the page.

Plupload's documentation is a little sparse for some of these settings.

Comment: For me "on the fly" meant during an event (and just before `uploader.start()`), I set `uploader.settings.multipart_params["name1"] = calcValue()`.

Comment: Good article on storing params in queue. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2506-storing-per-file-multipart-params-in-the-plupload-queue.htm

Comment: Do you need double quotes? i.e. is it `"name1"` or `name1`?

Comment: @hentrywright - For simple strings there's no difference :)

Comment: This is good, in the rare instance that you know the value of your post params at the early stage where you are defining and initializing your upload object. Often though, they may come from other form inputs.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `uploader.settings.multipart_params["name1"] = yourValue;` but `"name1"` must be declared in uploader config :

```
multipart_params : {
    "name1" : "value1",
    "name2" : "value2"
}
```

Comment: Well done. Able to listen to BeforeUpload and query form values and attach them to the previously declared mulitpart_params.  I have confirmed this method works and works well.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to dynamically add parameters on every file upload you can do this:

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up, file) {
    up.settings.multipart_params = {

        "parameter1": "value1",
        "paremeter2": "value2"

    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
uploader.settings.url = "upload.php?param1=whatever"
```

and just pass it as a get variable.

Answer (score 0):

More up to date for 3.xx
After files added use this as an example with DEPOSITImageUploader being the declared plupload change as you wish

```
BeforeUpload: function (up, files) {
            console.log("BEFORE UPLOAD ");
            var settings = DEPOSITImageUploader.settings;
            var params = settings.multipart_params;
            $.extend(up.settings.params, { deposit_id : $('#deposit_id').val() });
```