# Custom upload dir "on the fly" in Wordpress 3.6?

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading, plupload

Writing a plugin for Wordpress and cannot manage to set the upload folder. Found this when I googled:

```
$upload_dir = "images/objects" . (isset($_REQUEST['ObjectNo']) ? "/{$_REQUEST['ObjectNo']}"  : "");
$plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . BGREAL_PLUGIN_NAME;
$plugin_url = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . BGREAL_PLUGIN_NAME;

function sss_configure_upload_dir($path_data)
{
   global $upload_dir;
   global $plugin_dir;
   global $plugin_url;

   $path_data['path'] = $plugin_dir . "/" . $upload_dir;
   $path_data['url'] = $plugin_url . "/" . $upload_dir;
   $path_data['subdir'] = "/" . $upload_dir;
   $path_data['basedir'] = $plugin_dir;
   $path_data['baseurl'] = $plugin_url;

   return $path_data;
}
add_filter('upload_dir', 'sss_configure_upload_dir');
```

On the page where the uploader frame opens, I have got the following:

```
$upl = wp_upload_dir();
echo $upl['path'];`
```

Which echoes `C:\PATH\TO\HTDOCS\public_html/wp-content/plugins/bg_real/images/objects/11212`

The problem is, when I open the media upload frame and uploads an image, it save into `/wp-content/plugins/bg_real/images/objects` since the `$_REQUEST['ObjectNo']` is missing in the `async-upload` function.

I need the images organized in folders after the querystring `ObjectNo`.

Any ideas? Spent hours on Google etc. and tried different approaches but none seems to work.

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure I understand your question as I have no proficiency on WP. Maybe this can help anyway : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13382331/1236044

Answer (score 0):

I maintain the [Custom Upload Dir-plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) for WordPress. It enables users to have context-aware upload paths (eg: folders named after the current post or author, datetimes etc). It'd be trivial to modify my filters to include your querystring.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles upon this, you can use the `UPLOADS` directory constant from within your `wp-config.php` file:

```
// before including wp-settings.php
define( 'UPLOADS', WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/my-upload-target' );
```

That's it. The rest gets cared about automatically.