# Why am I getting "undefined" passed to the db? jquery php plupload

Tags: php, jquery, plupload

I am NOT having trouble passing something into my database, so the "may have already been answered" alert above and the associated link do not answer my question (Thanks for trying to help anyway). My problem is with the jquery variable.

Why is it when I pass `$('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val()` to the alert the variable pulls the correct information, but when I pass it to the url in the plupload function it does not and I end up with `undefined` in my database. Why might this be happening? permissions? jquery conflict?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#myForm input').on('click', function() {
   alert($('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
   });

});

$(function() {
$("#uploader").plupload({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'flash,html5,browserplus,silverlight,gears,html4',       
    url : 'upload.php?aud=' + $('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val(),
    max_file_size : '1000mb',
    max_file_count: 20, // user can add no more then 20 files at a time
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    rename: true,
    multiple_queues : true,
     //multipart_params : {
          //  aud : $('input[name="ageLimit"]').val()
    //},

    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    //resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},

    // Rename files by clicking on their titles
    rename: true,

    // Sort files
    sortable: true,

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip,avi"}
    ],

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : 'plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : 'plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
});

// Client side form validation
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

    // Files in queue upload them first
    if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
        // When all files are uploaded submit form
        uploader.bind('StateChanged', function() {
            if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                $('form')[0].submit();
            }
        });

         //uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up) {
             // up.settings.multipart_params.aud = $('input[name="ageLimit"]').val();
       // });    
        uploader.start();
    } else
        alert('You must at least upload one file.');

    return false;
});


});
</script>
```

here is the php code

```
//check for audience
    $aud = (!empty($_GET['aud'])) ? trim($_GET['aud']): "";
```

Comment: I suspect you can't pass URL-parameter GET data and multipart POST data at the same time -- or else you're retrieving it wrong server-side. Perhaps you're trying to retrieve a POST variable in your PHP, or perhaps plupload is stripping out your URL variables.

Comment: How do you handle the GET-parameters? Please show your PHP code.

Comment: the multipart data has been commented out for debugging.

Comment: //check for audience
  $aud = (!empty($_GET['aud'])) ? trim($_GET['aud']): "";

Comment: [Here's a similar question on the plupload forum](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1836), and a [simiar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535462/how-to-send-additional-data-using-plupload).

Comment: This is passing "":  uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up) {
                  up.settings.multipart_params = {
                           aud : $('input[name="ageLimit"]').val()
                        };   I have actually tired this before. Doing it through url seems to be the only thing that passes anything at all.
            }); I also changed the url back to the original code "upload.php"

Comment: I also changed the php to $_REQUEST still no go

Comment: Now it only pulls the first value: multipart_params : {
       aud : $('input[name="ageLimit"]').val()
    }, Why would the alert be correct and the multipart_params be incorrect?

Comment: `(isset($_GET['aud']) && !empty($_GET['aud']))`

Comment: @MarcB No, that's not necessary: [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) will first check if the variable is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that is because no radio button is checked yet when the `url` option is evaluated in the init of the uploader.

instead of

```
url : 'upload.php?aud=' + $('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val(),
```

have

```
url : 'upload.php',
```

then add, after the plupload call and before the `$('form').submit(` call :

```
var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

uploader.bind('BeforeUpload',function(upldr,file){
    upldr.settings.url = 'upload.php?aud=' + $('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
    // here some runtimes might need a upldr.refresh(); (Though I'm not sure, I guess I remember Flash would.)
    }
);
```

Hope this will help