# trying to pass a jquery variable into a query string

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have two radio buttons for which I want to get the checked value and then pass to a url query string:

here is the html

```
<h3>Please select an audience</h3>
  <p><input class="age" type="radio" name="ageLimit" value="allAge"/> All ages </p>
  <p><input class="age" type="radio" name="ageLimit" value="mature"/> Mature</p>
```

This is the js:

when I use this, the database pulls [object, Object]

```
url : 'upload.php?aud='+$('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val($('input:radio[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm')),
```

when I use this it only pulls the first variable

```
url : 'upload.php?aud='+$('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val(),
```

How do I get the checked variable to pass into the query string? I have looked at several similar questions on SO, but nothing treats a query string

Comment: I am not able to see your JS; could you update this please?

Comment: See the documentation for [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2). It expects a string as an argument not a jquery object.

Comment: the first one that pulls [object, Object] .. you are **setting** the value .. in the second instance that pulls the first variable, you are **getting** the value.. the jQuery **val()** method can be used to **set** and **get** a value - http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2 -

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery's [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to zip your form up into a query string for you:

```
$('#myForm').serialize()
```

or

```
$('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').serialize()
```

---

When you convert a jQuery object to a string, that's what you get, `[Object object]`. Your first example *sets* the value of your form element, and then returns the jQuery object so that you can chain additional methods on it.

Your second attempt, with `val()`, returns the value you're after. If you want to get *several* values, you'll have to select the elements, and then `map` them to their value, and then join the resulting array. But you shouldn't do this. You should use `serialize` to do it for you.

Comment: I'm sure this is an awesome solution, but I am total c#&p at jquery. Where do I put this? currently I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: Right where your existing code is. `url: 'upload.php?aud=' + $('input...','#myForm').serialize()`.

Comment: Now I'm getting an empty string from `url : 'upload.php?aud='+$('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').serialize(),` Do I still need `val()` in there anywhere? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No, but if your options aren't checked or are disabled, they serialize to `""`. You may also not be selecting the elements you think you are.

Comment: I just checked to see if options were disabled with this and they are not. Can you think of any other reason serialize() might not work here?
`if (!$('.age:radio').is(':disabled')){
    alert('The radio group is not disabled.');
}

if ($('.age:radio').is(':disabled')){
    alert('The radio group is disabled.');
}`

Answer (score 1):

Snaps to serialize above. I personally enjoy ajaxForm plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

If your goal is to get the selected radio value into a url then play around with it on jsfiddle (link below).

http://jsfiddle.net/NQ6wH/

```
<h3>Please select an audience</h3>
<form>
  <p><input class="age" type="radio" name="ageLimit" value="allAge"/> All ages </p>
  <p><input class="age" type="radio" name="ageLimit" value="mature"/> Mature</p>
</form>
<button id="testMe">Test Me</button>

$('#testMe').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = 'upload.php?aud=' + $('input[name=ageLimit]:checked').val();
    alert(url);
});
```

Comment: the test button says I'm getting the correct value, but when I do this I get an undefined value. Why might that be? `url : 'upload.php?aud=' + $('input[name=ageLimit]:checked').val(),`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem was somewhere entirely else and the uploader needed to evaluate/pass the radio button. Gahhhhh. Thanks for all the help! –

here's the link: [Why am I getting "undefined" passed to the db? jquery php plupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077744/why-am-i-getting-undefined-passed-to-the-db-jquery-php-plupload)

```
var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

uploader.bind('BeforeUpload',function(upldr,file){
upldr.settings.url = 'upload.php?aud=' + $('input[name="ageLimit"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
// here some runtimes might need a upldr.refresh(); (Though I'm not sure, I guess I remember Flash would.)
}
);
```